# Laravel Qr Code Not Working While Sending Email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, npm

I am using Laravel version "5.8"

I have installed composer require simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode - to generate qr code

to generate a Qr code on view i am using this code

```
 {!! QrCode::size(80)->generate('test data' ); !!}
```

but when i send the view over a mail , i dont get the Qr code over mail

this is my controller code

```
        $email = $userInfo['email'];
        $name = $userInfo['fname'];
        $subject = 'Test mail';
        $ccmail = 'test@gmail.com';
        $body = 's';
        Mail::to($email)->send(new Invitationmail($name,$subject,$ccmail,$body,$invitation_id));
```

View code

```
  </div>
    <td>{!! QrCode::size(80)->generate('asas' ); !!}</td>
    {!! QrCode::size(200)->generate('W3Adda Laravel Tutorial'); !!}
  <div>
```

Can some one help me with these ?
Thank you

Comment: What does `{!! QrCode::size(200)->generate('W3Adda Laravel Tutorial'); !!}` output? An `<img>` tag? Perhaps it's using a link without a domain (`/foo.png`) or a localhost URL that isn't resolvable?

Comment: @ceejayoz it generates a svg - xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

Comment: Not all email clients support SVG; you'll likely want to find a way to convert it to PNG.

Comment: thanks @ceejayoz , will have a look to convert it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I'm using laravel8. I found a few answers elsewhere, which showed me how to create a PNG (by default QrCode creates an svg which most email clients will not display).

I used the examples I found to create the QR code as a png which worked brilliantly when I viewed my email content on a dummy blade on a browser. I used the following code:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->size(100)->generate('QrCode as PNG image!')) !!}" />
```

However a number of email services (including Gmail) do not display images that use inlined base64 as above. Instead, they require you to add the base64 image as an attachment to the email and then reference that attachment in the img src.

Thankfully laravel (I'm using laravel8) has a really cool function that does this for you, so my code ended up looking like this (which worked):

```
              <?php
                  $qrCodeAsPng = QrCode::format('png')->size(500)->generate("my text for the QR code");
              ?>
              <img src="{{ $message->embedData($qrCodeAsPng, 'nameForAttachment.png') }}" />
```

The $message variable is one that is in every blade that is being sent as an email in laravel. In my case I did not want to create an actual image on the server, but if you wanted to use an image that you had stored you would use $message->embed().